# Manifest Merger fails for appComponentFactory

Tags: android, android-studio, manifest

Using Google's so called Material Design 2.0 requires you to add

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
```

in the app Gradle which also includes

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
```

which shows conflicts

Here's what the log says

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0-rc02] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91   

is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0-rc01] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).     Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.
```

Even after adding that to the Manifest  it shows 
Manifest Merger failed with multiple error

Answer (score 30):

This error is common nowadays:

When we get this types of error: When library is updated and providing use of AndroidX but we are using old one.

You can follow the steps to solve this:

- Migrate your project to **AndroidX:**

> With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can quickly migrate an
>   existing project to use AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to
>   AndroidX from the menu bar.
>
> **Note:** To migrate an existing project that does not use any third-party
>   libraries with dependencies that need converting, you can set the
>   `android.useAndroidX` flag to **true** and the `android.enableJetifier` flag
>   to **false**.

**THIS STEP WILL DO EVERYTHING AUTOMATICALLY THAT ALL ANSWER SAYS TO DO MANUALLY**

- You can check Overview of **AndroidX** [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx).
- More details for **[migration](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)**

Even If you get any other error like run-time build failed, then:

- Invalidate cache and restart

OR

- Clean your project

Hope it will helps to all.
Thank you.

Comment: I prefer this one, because it will auto backup for our old project.

Comment: Please remember to Click "Do refactor" in the bottom left after clicking "Migrate to AndroidX"

Comment: this solution works like a charm

Comment: Just to help further: set android.useAndroidX=true in gradle.properties, and same for enableJetifier

Answer (score 18):

> To fix this you have to add the **tools** namespace and apply the
>   suggested attributes to the application element recommended by the IDE.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="your.package.uri">

 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx">
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981156/tools-replace-not-replacing-in-android-manifest)

Comment: This is giving issue: tools:replace specified at line:23 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified

Answer (score 10):

> Suggestion: add '`tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"`' to
>  element at `AndroidManifest.xml`:5:5-19:19 to override.

If you added the `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` and still got trouble by fixing it, create a new project, copy-paste the codes and the same dependencies in there. After that, it should be fixed i hope.

---

If it didn't solve the issue, try adding these two:

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
android:appComponentFactory="androidx"
```

<sub>In `AndroidManifest.xml` > `<application` tag of course.</sub>

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "site.foxtransport.foxtaxi.whateverString"

Comment: Can you try with `android:appComponentFactory="androidx"`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried, thank you. It looks like in such a case  anything lower than API 28 is incompatible

Answer (score 7):

Replace all android dependencies with androidx ones in build.gradle file.

For example:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
```

Comment: This lead me to the solution for my setup! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Replace in dependencies
from:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
```

to:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score -1):

try :  replace rc01 >> alpha1 . It's working for me !

Comment: I think this can be a comment and not an answer

Answer (score -1):

I also had this issue and I migrated to AndroidX, following the official documentation. Only via Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX.

[Migration to AndroidX Official Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

Deselecting instant run worked for me. Not sure if it helps for everyone.