# Android X: tools:replace specified at line: for attribute, but no new value specified

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, androidx

I have tried many solutions on this website but still, the problem is not solved. The issue is due to Android X library. When I added Android X, this issue was resolved but it opened up new issue. How to fix this issue?

Earlier this error was coming:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:19:5-142:19 to override.
```

After I added `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"`, this error is came:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.mergeManifestsForApplication(AndroidBuilder.java:540)    
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeManifests.doFullTaskAction(MergeManifests.java:173)
```

Merging Error (in Android Manifest):

> Error: tools:replace specified at line:2 for attribute
>   android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified app main
>   manifest (this file), line 1

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    package="com.example"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:replace="allowBackup, android:appComponentFactory"
    android:allowBackup="false">

    ...

    <application
        android:name="com.example"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning,HardcodedDebugMode">
       ...
```

Comment: Have you checked this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54825603/1318946

Comment: By any chance are you using firebase? If yes the newest versions are on android X hence the error

Comment: @Ggriffo No. I am not using Firebase.

Comment: I faced this error when my project was not migrated to androidX & I tried syncing the CameraX library. After migrating everything is working fine.

Answer (score 114):

I think you are migrating to AndroidX libs.

Add below lines to **gradle.properties** file

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Remove `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` from manifest.

Replace import  from `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` to `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity` in activities. Use replace in project to expedite the process of refactoring.

[Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: Where should I replace android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity ?

Comment: @Lucky_girl You must be using `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`. This means you must have created children activities of this activity. Replace them with `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity `

Comment: I did everything same but getting this error : `Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(whateverString) from AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-53
 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:5-149:19 to override.
`

Comment: @AliAkram that happens when your app, that isn't configured for AndroidX, uses a library that actually uses AndroidX. What you should do is look at the library release history and see if there's a release prior to that libraries' switch to AndroidX. Finally write yourself a work item to convert your app to AndroidX - it can take quite a while depending on the size of the project.

Answer (score 43):

You can try adding:

```
android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"
```

To the tag `<application >` in your manifest.

Comment: This is not a good solution as it forces one to use API Level 28 or higher

Comment: Thanks, this is worked for me, but it is ok to keep using it even on production?

Answer (score 13):

I got same error in my project, I have resolved it
You can try it

Android Studio > Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX

[image]

Comment: No it automatically fixes all imports

Answer (score 8):

I added below lines inside `<application>` tag

`tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
 android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"`

below lines inside gradle.properties file

`android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true`

Rebuild your project.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I had updated Firebase and play services dependency, result in this issue.

**Reverted back the dependency updates and the error vanished**

Seems that the latest Firebase and Play Service dependencies are compatible with **androidx**.

Answer (score 5):

It often happened because you used **Androidx libraries** and **support libraries** at the same time. Some 3rd-party libraries may contain support libraries and other 3rd-party libraries may contain Androidx libraries, this can also lead this problem. If you have gradle environment in you PC, try "gradlew :app:dependencies" command in the terminal of Android Studio, this command will list all libraries including 3rd-party libraries of your project, and see which library or framework used Androidx libraries and which not. Then try to upgrade old libraries used support libraries, and this problem should disappear.

Answer (score 4):

migrate to android x

add below lines inside  tag

```
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
    android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"
```

then also add below lines inside gradle.properties file

```
  android.useAndroidX=true
  android.enableJetifier=true
```

Rebuild your project.

Answer (score 4):

**In build.gradle**

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

**In gridle.properties**
add following line

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

**In AndroidMenifest.xml**
in <menifest ...

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

and in <application ...
add following attributes

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        tools:targetApi="p"
```

Answer (score 3):

you need just add this code in **gradle.properties** file

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: How is that helping?

Comment: i dont have this file in project. I have a 3 or 4 years old app and trying to set it up

Comment: create a new project and copy all old files in the new project

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i was facing problem because of the firebase version i was using.
Downgrading the firebase version helped me.

> implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
>   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'

Answer (score 2):

in my case I have problem with

```
tools:replace="android:usesCleartextTraffic"
```

I have already use AndroidX, I have already have these properties in gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

the problem is I forget to set the value to be `true` (or it can be `false`, depends on your case)

```
<application
        android:label="myApp"
        tools:replace="android:usesCleartextTraffic"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> // I forget this line
```

Answer (score 0):

Just configure your manifest application tag this way

```
<application
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="m"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Media">
```

Answer (score 0):

source of these errors for me was adding v4 design support library for TabLayout.

thread [Manifest Merger fails for appComponentFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52135251/manifest-merger-fails-for-appcomponentfactory/53594162#53594162) helped,

after setting:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=false
```

I faced issues with tools name space.
Problem was, in manifest I had `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` but adding `android:appComponentFactory="androidx"` resolved at-least manifest merge errors.

However when tried to link setup TabLayout with ViewPager using, it seems pager needs to be `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` but i got `androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager`

```
        //attach pager adapter
        SectionPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new SectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        //attach viewpager with tablayout
        TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);
```