# Dependencies using groupid com.android.support and androidx.* can not be combined but found IdeMavenCoordinates

Tags: android, androidx

I want to upgrade Google libraries:

build.gradle (app):

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlin_version}"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1'
    // Here an error appears.
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:${supportLibraryVersion}"

    // These libraries are updated.

    // Google Maps.
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0"

    // Firebase.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'

    // Multidex.
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

build.gradle (project):

```
buildscript {
    ext.compile_sdk_version = 29
    ext.min_sdk_version = 16
    ext.target_sdk_version = 29
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.40'
    ext.supportLibraryVersion = "28.0.0"

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // Firebase.
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I get an error in the first support library. I don't have AndroidX, only 28.0.0. Updating any of Google libraries will lead to this error (Google Maps or Firebase).

> Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx.* can not
>   be combined but found
>   IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='com.android.support',
>   myArtifactId='loader', myVersion='28.0.0', myPacking='aar',
>   myClassifier='null'} and
>   IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='androidx.versionedparcelable',
>   myArtifactId='versionedparcelable', myVersion='1.0.0',
>   myPacking='aar', myClassifier='null'} incompatible dependencies
>
> Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and
>   libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such
>   incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support
>   libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version
>   lower than your targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible

I saw [Can I use library that used android support with Androidx projects.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033810/can-i-use-library-that-used-android-support-with-androidx-projects), [having problem and errors with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56519348/having-problem-and-errors-with-dependencies), https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/issues/128.

After compiling the project I receive in "Build Output" in line `android:supportsRtl="true"`:

> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED
>
> C:\Users\ ...\AndroidStudioProjects\ ...\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
>       Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>       is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:15:5-145:19 to override.

When I add to `<application>` tag in AndroidManifest `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` I receive another error:

> tools:replace specified at line:15 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified
>
> C:\Users\ ...\AndroidStudioProjects\ ...\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
>       Validation failed, exiting

(as in [Android X: tools:replace specified at line: for attribute, but no new value specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268865/android-x-toolsreplace-specified-at-line-for-attribute-but-no-new-value-spec)).

Should I migrate the app to AndroidX?

Comment: I solved it by migrating to AndroidX. I met another error (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56807023/androidx-could-not-determine-artifacts-for-androidx-multidexmultidex2-0-0) and fixed it.

Comment: May be helpful to others, updating google play services to latest cause this issue for me.