# AndroidX. Could not determine artifacts for androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0

Tags: maven, androidx

I try to migrate a project to AndroidX.

After 3 minutes of migrating it finished with error:

> Gradle import
>   errorsC:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\project\app\build.gradle***project
>   ':app': Unable to build Kotlin project configuration**Details:
>   org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all
>   dependencies for configuration
>   ':app:implementationDependenciesMetadata'.Caused by:
>   org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactResolveException: Could not
>   determine artifacts for androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0Caused
>   by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource
>   'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/room/room-runtime/2.0.0/room-runtime-2.0.0.aar'.Caused
>   by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException:
>   Could not HEAD
>   'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/room/room-runtime/2.0.0/room-runtime-2.0.0.aar'.Caused
>   by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection
>   during handshakeCaused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut
>   down incorrectly*
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
>
> Could not determine
>   artifacts for androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0
>
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/multidex/multidex/2.0.0/multidex-2.0.0.aar'.
>
> Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/multidex/multidex/2.0.0/multidex-2.0.0.aar'.
>
> Remote host closed connection during handshake SSL peer shut down incorrectly
>
> Try:
>
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

How to solve a problem with `multidex` and `Maven`?

build.gradle (project):

```
buildscript {
    ext.compile_sdk_version = 29
    ext.min_sdk_version = 16
    ext.target_sdk_version = 29
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.40'
    ext.supportLibraryVersion = "28.0.0"

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // Firebase.
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        ...
    }
    compileSdkVersion compile_sdk_version
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion min_sdk_version
        targetSdkVersion target_sdk_version
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            // Adds the "release" signing configuration to the release build type.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
}
```

UPDATE

I updated all libraries in dependencies. Then in project's build.gradle I added

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
```

to `repositories` in both branches. After compilation I got:

> What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
>
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:kapt'.
>
> Could not resolve androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0.
>
> Required by:
>
> project :app
>
> Could not resolve androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0.
>
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/room/room-compiler/2.1.0/room-compiler-2.1.0.pom'.
>
> Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/room/room-compiler/2.1.0/room-compiler-2.1.0.pom'.
>
> Remote host closed connection during handshake
>
> Could not resolve androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0.
>
> Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/androidx/room/room-compiler/2.1.0/room-compiler-2.1.0.pom'.
>
> Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/room/room-compiler/2.1.0/room-compiler-2.1.0.pom'.
>
> Remote host closed connection during handshake

Answer (score 4):

I added in `build.gradle` (project) these lines:

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
```

So, it looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.40"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Then synced gradle file. It downloaded some libraries from Maven. After compiling I got another error. Then I pressed `Sync Project with Gradle files` again.

See also https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate to understand what library and styles becomes what in AndroidX.

Strange, but after compiling and removing

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
```

back from `build.gradle`, the application run again.