# tools:replace specified at line:11 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified app main manifest (this file), line 10

Tags: android, android-manifest

When I build my project I get these errors :

> Merging Errors: Error: tools:replace specified at line:11 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified app main manifest (this file), line 10
>
> Error: Validation failed, exiting app main manifest (this file)

This is my Manifest :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="org.apoce.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />


    <application
        android:name="org.apoce.app.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">

        <!--activities-->
        <activity
            android:name="org.apoce.app.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
...
```

what i can do to fix this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android X: tools:replace specified at line: for attribute, but no new value specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268865/android-x-toolsreplace-specified-at-line-for-attribute-but-no-new-value-spec)

Comment: i use com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0 into my gradle not androidX

Comment: You have to use  androidX . Because some of your dependency using androidX this is why the conflicts comes .. Its just one click away ..

Comment: okay, i will try to megrate into androidX

Comment: no think happend its stay the same error