# Unity: Cant build to Android after adding Facebook SDK -- GRADLE ERROR : colliding-attributes

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, gradle, android-manifest

Unity 2019.3.13

My project already has several sdks / libraries..
Unity IAPs,
Unity push notifications,
Ironsource,
Gamesparks,

When I added the facebook sdk and went to build on Android I got a lot of errors

[image]

I found [in the Unity docs here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-troubleshooting.html)
it says
"Either remove the attribute from the library, or add a tools:replace attribute to your application tag, to indicate how the merge conflict should be resolved."

There are two AndroidManifest.xml files in the project. I could not find anything to do with "componentfactory" in either of them.
Also I do not understand that "suggestion"

```
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:3-121 to override.
```

************  EDIT  *************

In either of the AndroidManifest.xml files I replaced this line...

```
<application>
```

with this line...

```
<application tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
```

In either case I get errors when trying to build..
If I do do it on one file I get...

```
XmlException: 'tools' is an undeclared prefix. Line 4, position 16.
```

If I do it in the other one I get these errors...

[image]

**************   EDIT 2  *************************

I tried an application tag like this, [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58245436/toolsreplace-specified-at-line11-for-attribute-androidappcomponentfactory-bu?noredirect=1), to one of the AndroidManifest.xml files

```
<application tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory" android:appComponentFactory="@string/app_name">
```

And I got these errors

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem detalization:**

Facebook SDK for Unity has AndroidSupportLibraryResolver script which adds `com.android.support` dependency into gradle project. This script is compiled into FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Facebook.Unity.Editor.dll so you can't edit or remove it.

`com.android.support` library is obsolete. Almost of all other libraries and SDK already migrated to [androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) which should be used now.

If you have both dependencies in your project you will get such error.
But there is a tool called [jetifier](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier) which converts `com.android.support` dependencies into `androidx`. You just need to enable this tool.

**Solution:**

Found solution here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/androidx-corecomponentfactory-problem-on-2019-3.777584/#post-5193863

1. In Unity go to Project Settins -> Player -> Android -> Publishing Settings
2. Enable "Custom Main Gradle Template" and "Custom Gradle Properties Template"
3. Run Assets -> Play Services Resolver -> Android Resolver -> Force Resolve
4. Open Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle and add

```
([rootProject] + (rootProject.subprojects as List)).each {
    ext {
        it.setProperty("android.useAndroidX", true)
        it.setProperty("android.enableJetifier", true)
    }
}
```

right under `// Android Resolver Repos Start` line

5. Open Assets/Plugins/Android/gradleTemplate.properties and add

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

before `**ADDITIONAL_PROPERTIES**` line

Answer (score 0):

remove old sdk
in "Assets\FacebookSDK\Plugins\Android\libs"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqE01.png)