# Android Manifest merger failed with Material Date Time Picker

Tags: android

I was trying to add the following library:

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

After adding the dependency, It is showing me the following error.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-34:19 to override.

I added

> tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"

in the manifest, after adding its showing me following error :

> Merging Errors: Error: tools:replace specified at line:8 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified app main manifest (this file), line 7 Error: Validation failed, exiting app main manifest (this file)

I tried to solve it, but no luck. I visited a few similar links also.
Please suggest, what should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: @Pratikbutani wrong duplicate

Comment: add as attribute in your <application> tag of `AndroidManifest.xml` `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"`

Comment: @PratikButani I tried it, Its not working.

Comment: What you are getting after trying?

Comment: i think issue with your `MaterialDateTimePicker` try to downgrade version of `MaterialDateTimePicker` may be latest version is for `androidx` not for `android.support`

Comment: Check this one : https://stackoverflow.com/q/52135251/1318946

Comment: @PratikButani I have updated the question.

Comment: Try both : `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"`

Comment: You can't use AndroidX with Support Libraries. Migrate your project to AndroidX then the issues will be avoided.

Comment: @PratikButani That is also not working, to use android:appComponentFactory="whateverString" minSDKVersion should be 28, I made it 28 still it is showing few errors

Comment: @NileshRathod Tried downgrading the library version, still same issue.

Comment: @AndroidDev I had similar problem. By Adding following lines in gradle.properties file: 
`android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true`

solved conflicting errors for me.

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi Merger issues gets resolved by adding the lines you suggested, but more errors arises after that.

Comment: @AndroidDev Can you be more specific regarding the errors?

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi Just had a discussion with its develoer over github, so the issue is resolved by using version 3.6.4 as of 4.0.0 this library is using androidx

Comment: @AndroidDev Okay. Nice that's your issue has been resolved

Comment: @PratikButani Pls mark this question as not duplicate, since this was not the duplicate of what the links you shared.

Comment: @AndroidDev you can post answer as you got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a discussion with [its](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) developer over GitHub, so the issue is resolved by using version 3.6.4 as of 4.0.0 is using androidx

Comment: You can upgrade your version by this steps:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54825603/1318946