# How to properly migrate to Android X support libraries without AAPT Error?

Tags: android, androidx

How to properly migrate to Android X support libraries without AAPT Error ?
When i tried with the latest android studio feature :
by selecting **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX** from the menu bar.

I encountered AAPT Errors .

Is this due to the use of old support libraries inside my libraries which i have used?

Can anyone share the correct steps/checklist to be followed while migrating to Android X ?

Comment: Can you please post your logcat? or You can try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54825603/1318946