# Try to migrate AndroidX to Android AppCompat

Tags: android, android-manifest, androidx

I have errors when migrate from AndroidX to Appcompat. Here is log build:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:18:5-138:19 to override.
```

Comment: Check minimum required gradle version for AndroidX migration. If that is fine then add tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory" to application tag.

Comment: This error will go if you apply my anwser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manifest Merger fails for appComponentFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52135251/manifest-merger-fails-for-appcomponentfactory)

Answer (score 5):

So you want to migrate back to support from androidX. If that will be the case the remove below libs from build.gradle and add old support library instead.

```
androidx.core:core:1.0.1
```

And also remove below two properties in gradle.properties files.

```
android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true
```

**Or** if you want to migrate to Androidx then add these two properties to gradle.properties file.

```
android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: I have tried. But got some issues : 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Build log show this. I have add Multidex in build.gradle but it does not work

Comment: here is my build.gradle file :

Comment: Show me your gradle.properties file

Comment: multiDexEnabled true   un-comment this

Comment: I have try add multidexEnable true. but it does work

Comment: android.enableD8 = false comment this in gradle.properties file

Comment: yep. I have commented.
sometime my tool log :
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-ui.version'
sometime it's : More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/androidx.customview_customview.version'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189374/discussion-between-hussnain-haidar-and-dng-nguyn-vn).