# Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory updating Firebase libraries

Tags: java, firebase, gradle, build.gradle, androidx

I am trying to add firebase in my project but when I implement `'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.0'` and `'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'`.

`build.gradle`(here is the error)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
 compileSdkVersion 28
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.user.mikripoli"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }

 dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
 }
}

dependencies {
 implementation 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
 implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.4'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
  core:3.0.2'
 implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0'
 implementation 'com.github.ahmedshaban1:EasySlider:1.0.0'
 implementation 'com.liangfeizc:SlidePageIndicator:1.1.0@aar'
 implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
 annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```

}

the other gradle file:

```
buildscript {

 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
 }
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
 }

  allprojects {
    repositories {
     google()
     mavenCentral()
     jcenter()
     maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
     maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
   }
  }

  task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
  }
```

The error that show about `com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0`:

> Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx.* can not
>   be combined but found
>   IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='com.android.support',
>   myArtifactId='cardview-v7', myVersion='28.0.0', myPacking='aar',
>   myClassifier='null'} and
>   IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='androidx.coordinatorlayout',
>   myArtifactId='coordinatorlayout', myVersion='1.0.0', myPacking='aar',
>   myClassifier='null'} incompatible dependencies
>
> Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and
>   libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such
>   incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support
>   libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version
>   lower than your targetSdkVersion).

**Also** when I build the apk it shows this error:

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:13:5-354:19 to override.
>
> adding tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory" doesn't work though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manifest Merger fails for appComponentFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52135251/manifest-merger-fails-for-appcomponentfactory)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With new release, libraries are migrated from the Android Support Libraries to the Jetpack (AndroidX) Libraries.

The updated libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:

- **Upgrade com.android.tools.build:gradle to v3.2.1 or later.**
- **Upgrade compileSdkVersion to 28 or later.**
- **Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX); follow the instructions in [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).**

**Method-1 :**

add this two in your gradle.properties File, without updating anything

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

**Method-2**

if Method-1 doesn't solve your problem
do one thing
if you are using android studio version 3.2 or higher
go to **Refactor>Migrate to AndroidX...**

Comment: removing the tools:replace and adding the two properties to gradle.properties solved the problem for me

Comment: This worked for me. I'm taking this opportunity to express what a pain it is to develop in Android Studio as a user who's not in it on a daily basis. Every time I update Studio, the SDK, Gradle, etc., I risk spending days making everything work again. Fortunately, I found your answer pretty quickly this time. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

According to the [firebase site](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_june_17_2019) to solve this issue:

- Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX), you can do this by adding these two lines: `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` into file `gradle.properties` in the project root directory. Or you can do [another method](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)
- Upgrade `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to v3.2.1 or later (in project `build.gradle` file)
- Upgrade `compileSdkVersion` to 28 or later (in project `build.gradle` file)

Answer (score 2):

Either downgrade those `Firebase` dependencies - or [migrate](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) to `androidx`.

The Jetifier is rather useless, because having control over the *own* dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You are using both support libraries and androidx libraries and you can't do it.

Cloud Messaging version **19.0.0** is in the June release. Check the [official release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_june_17_2019) of Firebase Libraries:

> This release is a **MAJOR** version update and includes breaking changes.
>   **With this release, libraries are migrated from the Android Support Libraries to the Jetpack (AndroidX) Libraries.**
>   **The updated libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:**

- Upgrade `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to `v3.2.1` or later.
- Upgrade `compileSdkVersion` to `28` or later.
- Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX); follow the instructions in [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Answer (score 0):

28.0.0 was the last version of the original support libraries and these are no longer maintained. All functionality which was present in the support libraries is now a part of the AndroidX namespace and Google recommends that you move to AndroidX.

In Android Studio 3.2 and higher you can migrate by doing a `Refactor->Migrate to AndroidX`

However note that there may be some changes that you may have to do manually if you've specialized your configuration.

Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hyt7LR5mXLc) on the topic and the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Answer (score -1):

Try this and sync your project, if this can help you

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```