# Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, androidx

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.it.munchies"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.2.1.jar')
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.9@aar'
// routing
    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.0.7'
    implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
}

// For FCM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

when i updated android studio i had this error :

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:18:5-91:19 to override.
```

i've this error too but in gradle file ::::

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 23.0.1. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 more... (Ctrl+F1
```

Comment: open and follow this link, you'll get your answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/56667177/10340422](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56667177/10340422)

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification

Answer (score 1):

You are using both support libraries and androidx libraries and you can't do it.

Check the [official release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_june_17_2019) of Firebase Libraries:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  Service        |  Gradle dependency                           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Firebase Core   | com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Cloud Messaging | com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.0|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication  | com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

> This release is a **MAJOR** version update and includes breaking changes.
>   **With this release, libraries are migrated from the Android Support Libraries to the Jetpack (AndroidX) Libraries.**
>   **The updated libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:**

- Upgrade `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to `v3.2.1` or later.
- Upgrade `compileSdkVersion` to `28` or later.
- Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX); follow the instructions in [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Comment: i've migrated to androidx and i've this error  : error:package android.support.v7 does not exist

Comment: @zandroidarabapps Check which is the class related to the error. This package (and this import) should be removed with only androidx library.