# Build error due to conflict between Androidx and Android Support recent version

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, build-error

I am stuck with a build error due to some conflict as defined in the title. Here is my error:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
```

Here are my build.grade files:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.****.****"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.0.0'

implementation 'com.sdsmdg.harjot:vectormaster:1.1.3'

  }
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The build.gradle at the Module level is:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.40'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven{
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Can someone please provide me a pointer towards what is the issue over here? The error started only recently after I updated android studio and also added firebase storage into it

Just to add:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

gives me an error as follows:

```
Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx.* can not be combined but found IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='com.android.support', myArtifactId='support-fragment', myVersion='28.0.0', myPacking='aar', myClassifier='null'} and IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='androidx.versionedparcelable', myArtifactId='versionedparcelable', myVersion='1.0.0', myPacking='aar', myClassifier='null'} incompatible dependencies
```

Comment: you are mixing androidx libraries with the older support libraries.  You need to switch your support libraries to ones that work with androidx.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. But can't find where am I mixing it. No where have I directly used androidx

Comment: I believe your firebase version requires androidx.

Comment: This post explains something similar to your problem.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56667177/103131

Comment: Did you tried to let Android Studio migrate to AndroidX for you automatically? Is under Refactor tab

Comment: Yes it seems it is the Firebase version, which i updated yesterday. I am taking a backup. Will try to refactor

Comment: Yes I refactored to AndroidX and things are working fine. So everything has to be upgraded to AndroidX as of now it seems