# ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.support:support-v7:28.0.0 Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been already mirgate to AndroidX, but this error still happens..

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:17.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    implementation project(':beacon_controller:BluetoothLe')
    implementation project(':beacon_controller:BluetoothLe')
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v7:28.0.0'

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708058/build-error-due-to-conflict-between-androidx-and-android-support-recent-version

Comment: it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51450521/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v728-0/52533527

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51450521/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v728-0)

Answer (score 1):

remove this `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v7:28.0.0'`