# Failed in linking file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Dependency is appcompat dependency is underlined red and failed to build project fully

Changed all support libraries to use the compiledsdk version but still didnt work

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.7@aar'
implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.7'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.ixiDev:GDPRChecker:v0.2'
implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3@aar'
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.github.arcadefire:nice-spinner:1.4.3'
implementation 'com.github.mjn1369:prettydialog:1.0.4'
implementation project(path: ':SmoothCheckBox-master')
implementation project(':androidsaripaarmaster')
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation project(':rating-view')
implementation project(':pinlockview')
```

That is the error message that shows:
Compilation failed to complete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory updating Firebase libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56666925/manifest-merger-failed-attribute-applicationappcomponentfactory-updating-fire)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in this dependency `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0`. This location dependency use androidX Libraries.

Solution is: Either downgrade this dependency version or migrate to Androidx (whole project dependencies)