# Where can I find a JAR/AAR version of AndroidX library?

Tags: android, androidx

I'm currently developing an extension for App Inventor. And for this, I need to use the AndroidX library, but unfortunately, App Inventor still use the old support library. So, I was searching for it's (AndroidX) JAR/AAR version so that I can use it, but sadly, didn't found it anywhere. It'd be really nice if someone could help me with this.
Thanks :)

Comment: for migrate to androidX https://stackoverflow.com/a/56667177/10340422
if you want to know just versions you can visit, https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your project must be migrate to **androidx**

can also migrate project to **androidx** with one click

> Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX...

then

According to your question here you find **jar and aar** file

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll try it as soon as I get back to home. :)