# Error: MapFragment Cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment'

Tags: android

I had trouble creating an existing Google Map activity, even though I just yesterday built the app successfully with this Google Map activity, I checked between this project and the project yesterday I created, but nothing different. How to solve this problem?

Here is MapsActivity.class

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
```

Here is activity_maps.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

Here is error: 
Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting ERROR: Manifest merger failed after creation of Google Maps Activity project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56673212/getting-error-manifest-merger-failed-after-creation-of-google-maps-activity-pro).

Answer (score 0):

Hello I was able to solve with this code:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Retrieve the content view that renders the map.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Get the SupportMapFragment and request notification
        // when the map is ready to be used.
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation as what you did and why it solves the problem?