# How to fix manifest merger failed error on android studio?

Tags: android, manifest-merging

I've recently formatted my PC and set up the newest version of Android Studio. Now I have a problem with building projects. When I choose an empty activity, at the beginning I've got implementation error.

With some resource I've figured out it's about Turkish letters. Than I've changed it with big 'İ' letter, I've fixed the problem. Now I can build projects with empty activity.

But I would choose Google Maps Activity, and I'm having an error as like I added.

Any ideas how to solve?

Thanks in advice for any replies!

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:12:5-41:19 to override.

Comment: Clean, Build or Invalidate Catch and Restart.

Comment: Are you using `support-compat` and `androidX` both ?

Comment: This answer worked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52135251/manifest-merger-fails-for-appcomponentfactory Thanks a lot for fast responding. As you could see, I'm really new around here :)

Answer (score -1):

Add android:appComponentFactory in application Tag
 tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"