# Error occured during insertion of AdMob or Firebase Codes in gradle

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, admob, android-manifest

i have android studio project, when i insert AdMob or Firebase Codes in gradle, see this error

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:1-25:15 to override.
```

This is my manifest
[manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Wsww.jpg)

This is the gradle

```
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manifest Merger fails for appComponentFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52135251/manifest-merger-fails-for-appcomponentfactory)

Comment: did you try to add tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory" this to application tag in android manifest xml file?

Comment: yes i try it and not working , thank u for your answer

Comment: Even if I have created a new simple project
I get the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new [Firebase libraries](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_june_17_2019) and the new [Google Play Libraries](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019) **require androidx**.
Since you are using these libraries, you are using both support libraries and androidx libraries.

Check the note:

> This release is a **MAJOR** version update and includes breaking changes.
>   **With this release, libraries are migrated from the Android Support Libraries to the Jetpack (AndroidX) Libraries.**
>   **The updated libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:**

- Upgrade `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to `v3.2.1` or later.
- Upgrade `compileSdkVersion` to `28` or later.
- Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX); follow the instructions in [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Comment: oh thank you . i have uninstall android studio . and reinstall it

Comment: @MohamedSlimane It is not related to an installation. If you are using the new libraries it will always have this problem

Answer (score 0):

its working after add this code to `<application>`

```
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
    android:appComponentFactory="androidx"
```