# Manifest merger failed for V7

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest, android-support-library, androidx

i updated something and suddenly this happened

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute
>   application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-57:19 to override.

**i have looked into the other answers but i could not really figure out what to do or what to change**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.khali.nutriplan"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0-alpha'
implementation 'com.numetriclabz.numandroidcharts:numandroidcharts:1.0.18'
implementation 'com.xeoh.android:checkboxgroup:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0'
}
```

what is the proper library to use

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manifest Merger fails for appComponentFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52135251/manifest-merger-fails-for-appcomponentfactory)

Comment: Migrate to androidX or if you don't want to migrate add "tools:remove="android:appComponentFactory"" in Android Manifest file in <application> tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **both support libraries and androix libraries**, and you can't do it.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0'
```

You have **to migrate to Androidx**:

- Upgrade `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to v3.2.1 or later.
- **Upgrade `compileSdkVersion` to 28 or later.**
- Update your app **to use Jetpack (AndroidX)**; follow the instructions in [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Answer (score 0):

As mention here

> https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/193#issuecomment-486932223

Add two lines to `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```